# xrdp XFCE session trashed on first login

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, xrdp

I have a running `xrdp` connection from my MacBookPro (xfreerdp or MS Remote Desktop client) to a Linux Mint 19 XFCE 4.12.4.

If I log in physically on the Mint machine to create an XFCE session, then logout, everything is fine, I can connect remotely afterwards. But if I connect remotely right after Mint booted, the icons and the bottom bar are trashed / messed up and the remote session cannot be used.

[image: Messed up icons and bar]

Several references can be found, like [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2226340) or [here](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=8603), all of which are old (2014), supposedly fixed in XFCE 4.11 or left dangling without a solution. No reaction on Mint forum. So I'm turning here. Thanks for your help.